# Is it an efficient way to serialize JSON data in Java?

Tags: java, json, serialization

I don't know whether this question makes sense or not.
I have huge amount of JSON data with me. I am getting that data from Server to the Client side.

Is it good idea to serialize the JSON object in server side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have huge amount of JSON data with me.
>
> Is it good idea to serialize the JSON object in server side ?

No. JSON is already serialized, that's the point of the format.

If you have non-JSON data that you want to deliver to the client then, unless it is a string, you have to serialize it so that it is in a transmittable format.

Comment: That means the JSON data whatever I got in the Client side is serialized. So I just want to deserialize that in the Client side.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library)