# Composing a simple JSON response in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization

Imagine a simple JSON response such as:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "PEBKAC"
}
```

Given I have `boolean` and `String` variables, what's the simplest way to convert them to JSON in Java, without resorting to `String.format` and friends.

I'm more familiar with C#, where this is quite straightforward using the built-in [`JavaScriptSerializer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
var success = false;
var message = "PEBKAC";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(new { success, message });
```

Is there anything this straightforward for Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it an efficient way to serialize JSON data in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147028/is-it-an-efficient-way-to-serialize-json-data-in-java)

Comment: @RC, I don't care about efficiency. In this case I value simplicity.

Comment: Dogbert answer on the link was suitable to your needs (imho)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

using [JSON](http://www.json.org/)
**serialization**

```
  org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject();
  obj.put("success", false);
  obj.put("message", "PEBKAC");
  obj.toString();
```

**deserialization**

```
org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(responseAsString);  
obj.optBoolean("success"); // false
obj.optString("message"); // PEBKAC
```

using [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
public class MyObject
{
   private String message;
   private boolean success;
   public MyObject(String message, boolean success)
   {
      this.message = message;
      this.success = success;
   }
}
```

**serialization**

```
   MyObject obj = new MyObject("PEBKAC", false);  
   new com.google.gson.Gson().toJSON(obj);
```

**deserialization**

```
   MyObject obj = new com.google.gson.Gson().fromJSON(responseAsString, MyObject.class);
   obj.getMessage();
   obj.getSuccess();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code samples. They highlight some elegant options very well. I will check out `JSONObject` as it looks well suited to my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at gson?

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

//Henrik

Comment: Could you provide an example showing how to achieve the example set out in the question using GSON?

Comment: Here is a link to the referring docs for GSON:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Primitives-Examples
The section shows how to utilize the objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are JSON parser libraries available, one of which is Jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org). Jackson's ObjecMapper class (http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html) gives you functionality similar to the JavaScriptSerializer in C#.

Comment: This question is about serialising JSON, not parsing it. Please provide an example to prove how simple these libraries are to use. I'm using Jackson elsewhere in my application for parsing, but for serialising I haven't found as simple a means of generating JSON.

Comment: StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); jsonObjectMapper.writeValue(writer, obj) // where jsonObjectMapper is an instance of ObjectMapper and obj is the Java object to be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Use org.json.JSONObject

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

You can create a JSON object and then use the put method to add your values. 
Then call `jsonObj.toString()` to get the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at google's GSON. Is a Java library work work with JSON.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

And here you have some examples:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Primitives-Examples

**UPDATE**

The example just like @Ilya code is in the link. But this would be something like:

Object:

```
public class MyObj
{
   private String message;
   private boolean success;
   public MyObj(String message, boolean success)
   {
      this.message = message;
      this.success = success;
   }
}
```

Translating to JSON:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObj obj = new MyObj("PEBKAC",false);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"message":"PEBKAC","success":false}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example showing how to achieve the example set out in the question using GSON?

Comment: The link I've posted with the user guides gives you all this, and explains much more of this powerfull library. Including translating a JSON response directly to a Java Object.

Answer (score 0):

there are many simple libraries to deal with JSON in java, check: [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

there is no built in support in Java

Comment: I've seen this list. However many of them are more complex than I need in this case.

Comment: have you tried http://www.json.org/java/index.html  I've tried them and found very simple (used only first 7 classes)